# .NET CORE 2.0 Angular 5: Allowing Cors

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, cors

I am having some trouble allowing cors. I have set `server side` like so:

```
  app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200/").AllowAnyHeader());
```

Inside of the `configure` method of the `startup` class

When the my web API is hit, it will return the data fine.

However, the problem seems to be with Angular as in the I get the following error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Here is my angular web api call

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';;


@Injectable()
export class ProfileService {

    private baseUrl = 'api/profile/';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getLookups(step: number) {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:51658/' + this.baseUrl + 'lookups/' + step)
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions in your ASP.NET Core application? If yes, be aware that exceptions will **CLEAN** of any CORS headers set by the CORS middleware

Comment: @Tseng, thank you so much - interesting tidbit. Could you ellaborate or point to any docs on this?  I think we’ve been running into this forever

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Changed `builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200/")` to

```
builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
```

(Removed the '/')

Comment: I feel like i spend hours on this problem every time I am setting up a new project and this ends up being what the cause is.

Answer (score 17):

change your line in API with :

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyCredentials());
```

be sure you added `Services.AddCors();` in ConfigureServices()
stop the server and run again after changes are made.

Comment: `AllowAnyCredentials` shows up in red in ASP.NET Core 2.1. Is that in another package?

Comment: @JamesPoulose It should just be .AllowCredentials()

Comment: that's the only solution that worked for me. I was having this issue with react

Comment: Got exception after repeat your code. 
-- 
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The CORS protocol does not allow specifying a wildcard (any) origin and credentials at the same time. Configure the CORS policy by listing individual origins if credentials needs to be supported.'
--
Remove .AllowCredentials helped me

Comment: This might lead to an exception in Asp.net core >3.0:
The CORS protocol does not allow specifying a wildcard (any) origin and credentials at the same time. Configure the CORS policy by listing individual origins if credentials needs to be supported

Answer (score 7):

"WithOrigins" expect an array, not a string so maybe this is your case.
 However the minimum requirements for Cors to works in your case are:

In Startup.cs to add 
   `services.AddCors();` before `services.AddMvc();`   and  also:

`string[] origins = new string[] { "http://localhost:4200" };`
 `app.UseCors(b=>b.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().WithOrigins(origins));`

Again add it before `app.UseMvc(your routes ...)`

Or what you actually need doesn't matter the technology is to add a "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header with value the origin/origins in the response of the server which in .Net core 2 can be done like this (in any method in a controller):
          `ControllerContext.HttpContext
                  .Response
                  .Headers
                  .Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://localhost:4200");`

or globally - you can create a middleware that add this header to all the responses when the origin match.
Works also in Angular 6 and .Net Core 2 as separate applications.

Comment: `WithOrigins` expects a `params string[]` - that means multiple separate string parameters. A single `string` parameter is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is correct but still, for some people, it might not work the reason is the placement of statements. You must write all CORS related statements before useMvc()/addMvc.

In Asp net Core. The syntax will look like

In ConfigureServices method

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
                });
            });

// make sure the cors statement is above AddMvc() method.
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

In the Configure method

```
 app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

 // make sure cors is above add UseMvc method.
 app.UseMvc();
```

Here MyAllowSpecificOrigins is just a policy name and you can define at the top of your class

```
readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

U can configure Cors service by adding default policy in `ConfigureServices`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
                    });
            });

            .... add other services
        }
```

and don't forget to add `UseCors` in `Configure`

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
            {
                .. other middlewares 
                app.UseCors();
                app.UseRouting();
                .. other middlewares 
    
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try to add `AllowAnyMethod` to the chain.

```
builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200/").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
```

Comment: Same error. Like I say, I think its something to do with the Angular side because I can actually see the data being returned from the server, in the network tab of chrome developer tools.

Comment: Try to replace `WithOrigins` with `AnyOrigin`

Comment: The case is related to the given format. Try something another way

Answer (score -2):

Am serving angular on other port like :4200 or :4300 depending on the number of ports in use

so I have configured my asp.net core app in

> startup.cs

file to allow CORS from other sites

```
public class Startup
{


    readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {



        var config = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
            cfg.AddProfile(new ApplicationMappingProfile());
        });
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        services.AddSingleton(mapper);
        services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
    builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200",
                            "http://localhost:4300")
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);


        // Add EntityFramwork support for sqlServer
        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();

        //Add APplicationDbContext
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();


        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        //create a service scope to get an ApplicationDbcontext instance using DI
        using (var serviceScope =
            app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var dbContext =
                serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            //create the db if it doesn;t exist

            dbContext.Database.Migrate();
            DbSeeder.Seed(dbContext);
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins); 
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

please read asp.net core [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2)