# 400 Bad Request From WebApi In Angular 9 (using HttpClient)

Tags: c#, angular, rest, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Below is an Asp.net Core WebAPI which returns bad request. It works successfully when I call the web api via postman. but it doesn't work when I call with angular.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Login")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody]LoginCommand command)
    {
        var result = await Mediator.Send(command);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return BadRequest(result.Errors);
        }

        return Ok(result.Data);
    }
```

The response is being handled at the Angular side as follows:

login.services.ts

```
login(input: Login): Observable<any> {
let result;
this.apiService.post(this.loginPath, input).subscribe(
  data => {
    result = data;
    console.log("This should be the response???: ", data);
  },
  err => {
    console.log("err: ", err);
  });
return result;
```

}

api.services.ts

```
post(url: string, data: Object = {}): Observable<any> {

const headers = { 'Accept': '*/*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, HEAD','Content-Type': 'application/json', 
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With,content-type' }

let result = this.http.post<any>(`${this.apiURL}${url}`, JSON.stringify(data), { headers });
console.log(result);
return result;
```

}

Console error messages:

[image]

Network:

[image]

Comment: could you please set your chrome to english and retake the screenshots? The browser console output is crucial to helping you.

Comment: It looks like a CORS issue. Is the service running in a different application than the client?

Comment: Looks like your OPTIONS request is returning a 204. Are you sure about the API endpoint URL, esp the port numbers to be sure that you are running the API in the same url that your UI points to?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48464030/8385590

Comment: Yes, service running in a different application than the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure `CORS` in your asp.net core web api project `startup.cs`, add `app.UseCors()` between `app.UseRouting()` and `app.UseEndpoints()` if you are using asp.net core 3.0+:

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors( builder => 
{ 
  builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:5001")   
         .AllowCredentials() 
         .AllowAnyMethod() 
         .AllowAnyHeader(); 
});

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware